# Kubernetes, Ingress Nginx and too many redirects

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, ghost-blog

I’m installing a Ghost blog by using the stack Nginx + Kubernetes with Ingress Nginx. My K8s deployment and Nginx config are as below.

The problem is that when accessing the deployed blog, I got too many redirects error from the browser. And I guess that the root cause is the HTTPS URL is not configured properly in the Nginx ingress but I haven’t got the right way to resolve it. Someone can point me to what’s wrong here?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-blog
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my-blog.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: my-blog
            port:
              number: 2368
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-blog
  name: my-blog
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 2368
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: my-blog
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-blog
  name: my-blog
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-blog
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-blog
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: url
          value: https://my-blog.com
        image: ghost:latest
        name: my-blog
        ports:
        - containerPort: 2368
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

```
server {
    server_name my-blog.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_intercept_errors  on;
        proxy_pass http://k8s_cluster;
    }

    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-blog.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-blog.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

}
server {
    if ($host = my-blog.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server_name my-blog.com;

    listen 80;
    return 404;
}
```

Comment: where you have set your nginx file ? how your traffic is moving ? ingress to ngin pod or howmany pod are running ?

Comment: @HarshManvar
The Nginx config file is set for a load balancer where getting all traffics from users before forwarding them to the inside nodes of K8S.
The flow is users -> Internet -> Load Balancer (Nginx) -> Ingress Nginx -> Service
Just one pod is running for the test now

Comment: Ideally you should not be using that just create the load balancer type service of Nginx and use that IP into DNs and you are done. You have to install the Nginx controller that’s it no need of file config

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are using Nginx config if you are using the Nginx ingress.

it's an issue due to the HTTPS redirection at the Nginx ingress side

You should have to implement the SSL termination at Nginx ingress level

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: blog
  labels:
    app: blog
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: blog
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: blog
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: blog
        image: ghost:2.6-alpine
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 2368
        env:
        - name: url
          value: http://my-blog.com
```

run your site with plain HTTP and terminate the SSL at ingress nginx so your site will run on HTTP and traffic from ingress to inside cluster will run on HTTP. Your flow will be something like

```
Internet HTTPs > ingress HTTP > kubernets svc HTTP > deployment > pods > container
```

You have to set your cert at ingress level for that you can store the cert inside the Kubernetes secret and attach that secret to ingress so your site will run on HTTPS

**Ingress example**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: service-ingress
  annotations:  
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    #certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-staging
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - service1.example.com
    secretName: letsencrypt-staging
  rules:
  - host: service1.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: service1
          servicePort: 80
```

This way your site will run on the HTTPS but SSL get terminated at Nginx level.

Your SSL cert will be store in K8s secret in above example you can see secret name `letsencrypt-staging`

Ref : https://medium.com/@harsh.manvar111/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-and-cert-manager-ssl-setup-c82313703d0d

Comment: The first Nginx is used as a load balancer of the whole system, that's why I keep both it and the Nginx Ingress.
Changing the URL variable from HTTPS to non-HTTPS will make the deployment works but it's not what I'm looking for because some features of Ghost will not run properly if the URL is defined as non-HTTPS while users access from the browser via an HTTPS URL

Comment: Check for Nginx ingress controller and ingress you can create LB and use that IP as dns